# c++ - ::operator new[] and allocation for my custom container

Tags: c++, arrays, containers, new-operator, allocation

I'm having a problem which I can't wrap my head around.
I'm writing my own container which is more or less like an `std::vector<T>` and I don't know how to solve the problem around allocating memory for the objects.

Lets say for instance that I write a wrapper around an array and want to allocate data like this:

```
T* cArray = new T[size];
cArray[index] = std::move(obj);
```

If the obj doesn't have a default constructor which doesn't take any parameters Ill get a error: "Class: no appropriate default constructor available".

So I though i could solve the problem by not calling the obj's constructor by using operator new: `static_cast<T*>(::operator new(sizeof(T)*this->cap))` and this works only if I use built in types like `int, double and floats` as members for my Test obj.

If I do something like this:

```
struct Test
{
    Test(int x){}
    std::string s;
    double d;
}

MyVector<Test> vec;
vec.push_back(Test(1));
```

I get a runtime error if I try to assign data to the location in my push_back function which contains the following line:

```
cArray[index] = std::move(obj);
```

in file: xmemory0 on line 106:

> `Expression: "(_Ptr_user & (_BIG_ALLOCATION_ALIGNMENT -1)) == 0`

Again, this is only a problem when I'm not using built-in types. If I remove the `std::string` as a member everything works as expected. I have no idea what the cause of the problem might be nor do I know how to solve it after hours of searching.

Do you guys know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, at least the first half of it. Which is to allocate raw memory, rather than using `new Test[N]`. But you still need to construct your objects, which you can do using placement new. Given a pointer `p` which points to a location where you want to construct an object, you can do this:

```
new (p) Test(...constructor args...);
```

Also note that when you are done with the object, you will need to call the destructor manually:

```
p->~Test();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer mate, i solved the problem using all 3 of your answers, dont know which one i should mark. Also its kind of nice that my custom vector is way faster than std::vector on insertion even though it should never be used for production code.

Answer (score 1):

One answer is to not store `T[]` but instead store something of the same size and alignment requirements (the choice is most often [aligned_storage](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage)). Then you use the [placement `new`](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new) operator to construct items within it, e.g.

```
new (&carray[index]) T(...args)
```

When you are done with items you need to manually call the destructor on each item.

Comment: Thank you for your answer mate!

Answer (score 0):

That's the right way to allocate the memory. But you still need to call the constructor eventually, to turn the empty bytes into an object. (And later on you need to call the destructor.)

You'll need to use "placement new" to invoke the constructor:

```
new (&carray[index]) Test(obj)
```